# running Hadoop jar format

Tags: linux, hadoop

So I am passing this into the command line:

```
    hadoop jar target/lab2-1.0.jar edu.sjsu.cs185C.HousesDriver      
/home/mapr/Desktop/lab2/DATA/ train.csv /home/mapr/Desktop/lab2/OUT
```

When I run this I get a usage error:

```
usage: hadoop jar -classpath $CLASSPATH:lab2-1.0.jar  edu.sjsu.cs185C.HousesDriver
<inputfile> <outputdir>
```

Does anyone know why I am getting this?

Comment: Your input directory must exist *on Hadoop* (whether that's HDFS or MaprFs)... I find it difficult to believe you have a Desktop folder in your Hadoop cluster

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about hadoop, but could it be that you have a space before "train.csv" ?   Looks like HousesDriver expects 2 parameters, not 3.  Try removing the space in:

```
/home/mapr/Desktop/lab2/DATA/ train.csv
```

Comment: I tried that. I got this error: Input path does not exist: maprfs:///home/mapr/Desktop/lab2/DATA/train.csv

Comment: Sounds like a separate issue.  Is the file at that URI?  Is the full URI even valid?

Comment: yes I checked and made sure that it was the right path for that file

Comment: Is the "maprfs:" correct?  Maybe it should be a different service?   Or try getting rid of the leading "/" in your parameter.

Comment: I never set maprfs though. It only complains when the path is wrong and if I get rid of that error, I get the format error

Comment: Well maybe there's more setup you need to do, regarding this maprfs.  Anyhow, if it didn't work by passing in just "home/mapr/Desktop/lab2/DATA/train.csv" (i.e. without the prefix "/") then I'm out of ideas.  At least I solved your original question! :)  G'luck.